# How do you specify a requirements file in setuptools (setup.cfg)

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to migrate an old package that was using setup.py and requirements.txt in python2 to use setup.cfg in python3.

Setuptools' documentation states you can specify requirements as a list (which I've resorted to doing) or as a file ([see the docs here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#options), they say either file or list-semi).

How do I go about specifying a file for the package to use instead?

Current configuration example:

```ini
[metadata]
name = example
version = 2.0.0

[options]
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
    PyYAML==6.0
    requests==2.27.1
scripts =
    scripts/example_script.py

[options.packages.find]
where = example
```

What I'd like it to look like:

```ini
[metadata]
name = example
version = 2.0.0

[options]
include_package_data = True
install_requires = file:requirements.txt  # or something like this
scripts =
    scripts/example_script.py

[options.packages.find]
where = example
```

and requirements.txt being a regular requirement file:

```
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.27.1
```